# Swap a broken key with a different key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, swap

My keyboard has one broken key, the equal button "=". I would like to swap this important key with a less important one, say the "Home" key. I heard that xmodmap or xkeycaps could help but I can't find the keycode or keysym of the broken key (because it isn't responsive).

How do I permanently swap the two keys, of which one is broken?